# Method to save networkx graph to json graph?

Tags: python, json, graph, networkx

Seems like there should be a method in networkx to export the json graph format, but I don't see it. I imagine this should be easy to do with nx.to_dict_of_dicts(), but would require a bit of manipulation. Anyone know of a simple and elegant solution?

Comment: What exactly is the JSON graph format?

Comment: basically a list of nodes and adjacencies, but sorta confusing with a simple and an extended version:
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Docs/files/Loader/Loader-js.html

Comment: @Bob Hi, do you know, how to read in this from c++ ?

Answer (score 21):

This [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html) contains a full description

A simple example is this:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_edge('a', 'b')
print json_graph.dumps(DG)
```

You can also take a look at the [Javascript/SVG/D3](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/browser/networkx/examples/javascript) nice example on adding physics to the graph visualization.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'networkx.readwrite.json_graph' has no attribute 'dumps'

Comment: The link to the example adding physics is broken.

Answer (score 12):

Generally I use the following code :

```
import networkx as nx; 
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph;
G = nx.Graph();
G.add_node(...)
G.add_edge(...)
....
json_graph.node_link_data(G)
```

it will create json formatted graph in which the nodes are in `nodes` and edges in `links`
in addition to other information about the graph (directionality, ... etc)

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer because json_graph.dumps no longer exists: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html

Answer (score 8):

Here is a JSON approach that I just did, together with code to read the results back in.  It saves the node and edge attributes, in case you need that.

```
import simplejson as json
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
# add nodes, edges, etc to G ...

def save(G, fname):
    json.dump(dict(nodes=[[n, G.node[n]] for n in G.nodes()],
                   edges=[[u, v, G.edge[u][v]] for u,v in G.edges()]),
              open(fname, 'w'), indent=2)

def load(fname):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    d = json.load(open(fname))
    G.add_nodes_from(d['nodes'])
    G.add_edges_from(d['edges'])
    return G
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. In particular, 'DiGraph' object doesn't have an attribute 'edge.'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Save graph
nx.write_gml(G, "path_where_graph_should_be_saved.gml")

# Read graph
G = nx.read_gml('path_to_graph_graph.gml')
```

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the solutions didn't work for me. From the `networkx 2.2` [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle.html#networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle):

```
nx.write_gpickle(G, "test.gpickle")
G = nx.read_gpickle("test.gpickle")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of Abraham Flaxman's answer for networkx 2.7:

```
def save(G, fname):
    nodeArr = []
    for node in list(G.nodes(data=True)):
        print('node:', node)
        nodeArr.append(node)

    edgeArr = []
    for edge in list(G.edges()):
        print('edge:', edge)
        edgeArr.append(edge)

    graphDict = { 'nodes': nodeArr,
                  'edges': edgeArr}
    json.dump(graphDict, open(fname, 'w'), indent=2)

def load(fname):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    d = json.load(open(fname))
    G.add_nodes_from(d['nodes'])
    G.add_edges_from(d['edges'])
    return G
```

Answer (score -1):

Are the nodes and edges enough information? If so, you could write your own function:

```
json.dumps(dict(nodes=graph.nodes(), edges=graph.edges()))
```