# How to construct a graph using a list of tuples in python in networkX?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to make a graph from a list of tuples stored in a variable. I found `G.add_edges_from(e)` for making graph using list of tuples. but the problem is that this does not work and when i try to for example print the graph it returns `None`. I appreciate answers that solve my problem. I use the code below to make the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

e = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
G = nx.Graph()
g1 = G.add_edges_from(e)
print(g1)
```

**Update:**
I testes this code but again give None when trying to print:

```
e = [[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)],[(10,20),(10,30),(20,30)]]
graph_list = []
for i in e:
    graph_list.append(nx.Graph().add_edges_from(i))

print(graph_list[0].nodes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down shall we?
You assigned a list of edges in e, then you made a graph with G.
However, your issue is you're trying to assign g1 to what the method `add_edges_from` returns (which is None).
What you actually want is something like this:

```
import networkx as nx

e = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(e)
print(G)
```

Since the `add_edges_from` method returns `None` it is working as intended, you should try printing your original graph instead. I hope this helps and clarifies things for you!

Edit:
If you insist on just using the list of tuples, you can just do away with variables. Use lists to store graph objects instead, keep storing them in a loop as such:

```
e = [[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)],[(10,20),(10,30),(20,30)]]
graph_list = []
for i in e:
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(i)
    graph_list.append(G)

print(graph_list[0].nodes)
print(graph_list[1].nodes)
```

Then you can use indices to get each specific graph you make (which would be stored separately in the list)

Or you might want to start dumping each graph in a json file ([answered here] ([Method to export networkx graph to json graph file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133009/method-to-export-networkx-graph-to-json-graph-file)))

Which can solve your RAM issue

Comment: thank you for you response. yes you are right. now i understand where i am doing wrong. actually, want to make several graph. because of that i need to store them in variables such as this example: ```g1=nx.from_numpy_matrix(m1)```. but instead of matrix, i want to use a list of tuple. can you suggest any solution for this to create several graphs from different list of tuples and store them in variables to use them later?

Comment: In this case `nx.from_numpy_matrix` is a totally different method, and its much more fitting to your case, since it does actually return a graph.
From the docs:


`from_numpy_matrix(A, parallel_edges=False, create_using=None)
    Returns a graph from numpy matrix.`

So in this case you are totally fine to assign them to whatever variables you like

Comment: but since matrix needs more RAM, it is not applicable for my problem.

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate what you want

Comment: I tested as you said. but again gives None as output. You can check the code in **Update** section

Comment: I updated the code in my original edit, check it out. That should suffice.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. thank you. it solved the problem