# Can I pickle in python 3 and then unpickle in python 2?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, networkx, graphviz

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following: I have a `networkx`graph that I would like to draw as a [circular tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/circular_tree.html). This requires `Graphviz` and either `PyGraphviz` or `Pydot`, which are not available for Python 3.

I'm considering the option of serialising the graph-object in python 3, and then de-serialising it in a python 2 environment where I could draw it. It's, however, unclear to me what the potential issues are with this type of approach since I cannot assume that the respective objects are similar in both environments.

Apart from actually trying this out (I currently have no python 2 environment on my machine), is there any way to find out if this is possible? Or would it simply make more sense to follow a different route by either exporting to a different format (e.g. gephy), and perhaps even doing the drawing outside of python?

Comment: the best way would be to make your object state compatible with standard python structures and use `json` to serialize. No surprises.

Comment: Upgrading a project to Python 3 is *not that hard anymore*. Consider creating a pull request for either PyGraphviz or Pydot to add support?

Comment: The reverse question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3

Comment: `graphviz` is available for Python 3 though

Comment: json definitely seems to be an option, as explained in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162909/method-to-save-networkx-graph-to-json-graph)

Comment: Actually, `PyDot` claims to support Python 3, did you actually try using it?

Comment: I didn't try "using" pydot, but did try to install it. At least on anaconda it leads to the following error: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pydot -> pyparsing 1.5.6 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.5*

Comment: Oh, and PyGraphviz supports Python too.

Comment: @PatrickAllo: it sounds as if you already have Pyparsing 1.5.6 installed, Pydot requires 2.1.4 or newer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: After some more fiddling (I did already have Pyparsing 2.1.4) I have all the required modules installed. The last bit was to notice that there was a mistake in this online example: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/circular_tree.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can dump data in Python 3 to load it again in Python 2. You probably want to set `fix_imports`, as well as use a protocol lower than 3. From the [`pickle.dump()` documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

> If *fix_imports* is true and *protocol* is less than 3, pickle will try to map the new Python 3 names to the old module names used in Python 2, so that the pickle data stream is readable with Python 2.

Protocol version 2 is supported in Python 2.3 - 2.7.

However, consider some of the alternatives:

- There are three Graphviz packages that support Python 3:

  - [`graphviz` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) supports Python 3.3 and up.
  - `pydot` has supported Python 3 since version 1.2.0, released July 2016. They project [tests every commit on Python 3.5](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/master/.travis.yml).
  - `PyGraphviz` has supported Python 3 since version 1.3, released September 2015. The project [tests on 3.5 and 3.6](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/master/.travis.yml).
- Use a different serialisation format. JSON should be able to handle a graph just fine.